# Retrieve value from Json object with field having dots and hyphen in powershell

Tags: powershell, convertfrom-json

I want to retrieve value of a field present in json object. The filed name has dots and hyphen.

For eg:

```
$json = @"
{
"Stuffs": 
    {
            "Name.new-name": "Darts",
            "Type": "Fun Stuff"
    }
}
"@
```

How can I get the value `Darts`?

I tried some approaches like

```
$x = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$x.Stuffs.(Name.new-name)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please specify your exact problem. What happens exactly when you try to get the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$x.Stuffs.'Name.new-name'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24574891)

Comment: ...it literally does..replace the last line in the original question with what I wrote above, and you'll get the value "Darts" outputted.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please read the links I provided on how to write good answers. A code Snippet without any exnplanation is not a sufficient answer.

Comment: Regardless of @Clijsters' criticism, this a perfect answer for how to escape JSON properties which contain dashes. Thanks!